# How to compare two JSON files in python 2.7?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have two files filled with JSON objects. One is converted from XML using the Python module `xmltodict`. Once I have all the XML as dicts I convert them to JSON objects by using `json.dumps`. In the other file I have a bunch of JSON objects from an HTTP GET request. My goal is to compare the first file to the second file and if the first file has a JSON object where the `name` key doesn't match any of the objects `name` keys in the second file then it gets added to the second file. My question is does anyone have a suggestion how to do this? Or will I just have to resort to cold hard parsing? The psuedocode below is how I currently think to accomplish this:

```
postFlag = 0
for obj1 in file1:                      #for each JSON object in first file
    for obj2 in file2:                  #compare to each JSON object in second file.
        if obj1.name == obj2.name:      #if they match,
            postFlag = 0                #prepare to not post
            break                       #and go to next JSON object in file1
        else:                           #if they dont match
            postFlag = 1                #prepare to post
    if postFlag == 1:                   #if went through all obj2 and no match, then add to file2
        add obj1 to file2
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider something like following codes

```
dict_1 = { o.name: o for o in file1 }  # Construct a dict of name:object
# Use set operation to find the name not in file2
for need_insert in set(dict_1) - set([ o.name for o in file2 ]):
    add dict1[need_insert] to file2
```

Answer (score -1):

You need something like [this](http://tlrobinson.net/projects/javascript-fun/jsondiff)? Have you tried [JSON tools](https://bitbucket.org/vadim_semenov/json_tools/src/75cc15381188c760badbd5b66aef9941a42c93fa?at=default)?

```
pip install json_tools
```

and from the command line try

```
json diff file1.json file2.json > output.json
```

and then use the output for further processing.

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the links for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked pages change.

Comment: Not quite. The JSON objects in the two files don't necessarily have the same data. The only data that is confirmed that they all share is the `name` key

Comment: From the output you keep only the data that you need